# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource when calling WebAPI

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm trying to call my WebAPI, but I'm always get the error `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present`

Following the [Using Cors](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) article, we have the code below, but it always falls `onerror` method

```
// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // XDomainRequest for IE.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}

// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
function getTitle(text) {
    return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest() {
    // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
    var url = 'http://localhost:56280/api/Meta/GetListMetas';    
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    if (!xhr) {
        alert('CORS not supported');
        return;
    }

    // Response handlers.
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var text = xhr.responseText;
        var title = getTitle(text);
        alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
    };

    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
    };

    xhr.send();
}
```

I've tryied the `JSONP` also but without success again, falls on `error` method

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: "http://localhost:56280/api/Meta/GetListMetas"
    }).success(function (data) {
          alert(data)
    }).error(function (da) {
    });
```

**WebAPI**

I made a pretty simple API to do the sample

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class MetaController : ApiController
    {
        public string GetListMetas()        
        {
           return "1";
        }
    }
```

I've tryied serialize the return also, bu without success.

Someone can help me ?

**UPDATE**

Below, I attach the request header

[image]

Comment: Have you used Chrome's Developer Tools (or similar for IE/FF/Safari) to see the response you get from the server *INCLUDING HEADERS* when you call `api/Meta/GetListMetas`?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos I updated my question with a image where we can see the header request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as [Vaughn Okerlund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5070580/vaughn-okerlund) mentioned, is in the request made by the client.
The request is blocked by the server cause it does not recognize the client's request.

You can [enabled](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html) the origin white-listing the domain where the client is running:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var corsAttr = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:7185", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

As you can see I've enabled all the request for every verb from this domain:

```
http://localhost:7185
```

If you configure everything there you don't need

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

on your controller.

Considering your client is hosted in `http://localhost:7185/` you can use jQuery to call the server simply using this syntax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:56280/api/Meta/GetListMetas',
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    // crossDomain: true,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    //complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    //},
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials), it seems the issue is that in your controller's response to the service's request you're sending the wildcard header (*) for the origin rather than specifying a domain to allow. In order to send a credentialed request, the server has to grant access to a specific domain:

> Important note: when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.  The above example would fail if the header was wildcarded as: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.  Since the Access-Control-Allow-Origin explicitly mentions http://foo.example, the credential-cognizant content is returned to the invoking web content.  Note that in line 22, a further cookie is set.

Comment: @VaughnOkerlung I saw something strange, following the article in your answer, it works fine, passing through the onLoad method.